# Python memory overflow when looping over large numpy array of ints, one-hot conversion

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

`x` is shape `(45000,3,128,128)` numpy array of image pixel values ranging from 0-255.

I would like to make a one-hot encoding of `x`, and I was trying to do it in the following manner:

```
#x.shape = (45000,3,128,128)
n_frames = x.shape[0]           # (45000)
flatdim  = np.prod(x.shape[1:]) # (49152)
x_flat   = x.reshape((n_frames,flatdim)) # shape=(45000,49152)

x_1h = np.zeros((n_frames,flatdim,256))

for s in xrange(n_frames):
    cur = x_flat[s] # current frame
    for i in xrange(flatdim):
        x_1h[s][i][cur[i]] = 1
```

`x_1h` then, is a sparse matrix, where every pixel value in `x` is represented by a (256,) array with a single 1 in the pixel value's corresponding index and zeroes elsewhere.

Perhaps there is a more pythonic way of doing this that does not require memory caching massive arrays, but I am unaware of a cleaner method and I need to encode the array like this.

Unfortunately the python process responsible for this conversion quickly exceeds memory and gets killed.

Total system memory (physical): 32.00 GB

Could anyone help me with more memory-friendly code that performs the encoding I need?

**Edit,** Why I want this encoding:

The array will be used in a chainer neural network for image prediction. I cannot use softmax cross-entropy on the original `x`, since softmax cross-entropy expects a probability distribution and truth label. This is my (perhaps stupid) attempt to convert an array of continuous reals to a sort of pseudo probability distribution. So if a pixel value is predicted to be 0.53122 (approx. 135.4611), then the "distribution" of the corresponding values in `xhat` would have 0.5389 in the 135th (136) position, and 0.4611 in the 134th (135) position. I would then use the next frame, with the binary encoding as the truth label.

Comment: Also mention the total memory that is being filled due to running this and the total ram on your system.

Comment: How do you intend to use this array? With `sklearn`? Or some other package? Add the relevant tags.

Comment: what is the dtype of your initial array? by picking the smallest dtype capable of storing 0-255 (`uint8`?) you can reduce the memory used.

Comment: and your x_1h can be an array of dtype `bool_`

Comment: `45000 * 49152 * 256` is 527 "gigs" so even if you use a single bit per cell it's 66 GB of memory required.  Which is probably not reasonable.  So you should tell us why you're doing this.

Comment: @hpaulj, array is intended to be used in a chainer network, with softmax cross-entropy.

Comment: x is uint8. That is a great idea changing x_1h to bool. 
I will explain why I need this encoding in post.

Comment: You mentioned `"x_1h then, is a sparse matrix,"`. So, shouldn't it be a 2D matrix?

Comment: @JohnZwinck if you divide it by 8bits/byte it's 'only' 71GB, but that's still too large for his memory

Comment: PS. have you tested this method with less frames to see if this type of input works for your post-processing?

Answer (score 0):

If you find a way to store the intermediate result somewhere you can perhaps do it more efficiently by iterating over the values (0-255). 
Most of the times I work through pandas and not numpy directly, so this syntax is probably not correct. and for Python2, use `xrange` instead of `range`.

```
max = 256
for i in range(max):
    x1_h_part = np.zeros((n_frames,flatdim), dtype='bool_')
    x1_h_part[x_flat==i] = 1
    #store x1_h_part
```